# Cant include window.js in magento frontend

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Hi guys iam stuck at a point and i cant go ahead.

I am trying to include window.js file in my frontend. As prototype is located at magento root folder. I have been following tutorial at

```
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-pop-ups-with-window-js-in-the-front-end-with-magento/
```

but it didn't seem to work for me. When i apply the code it throws an error that "Window is not a constructor".

Where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this inside one of your layout files.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>prototype/window.js</script>
        </action> 
    </reference>
</default>
```

If you don't need it in all the pages then replace the `<default>` handle with the appropriate page handle

Comment: Check the source of the page and see if the file is included. Maybe is included an you are using it wrong.

Comment: I have checked the source too. Skin Js are being inlcuded but when it comes to root js it doesnt include